# Unable to install Flask in PyCharm

Tags: flask, pip, installation, pycharm, windows-8.1

I have trouble installing Flask in PyCharm. I got the following errors when I tried to run `pip install flask`.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rohit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7tccrr01\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rohit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7tccrr01\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q_wdekk3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7tccrr01\MarkupSafe\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe
    copying src\markupsafe\_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe
    copying src\markupsafe\_constants.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe
    copying src\markupsafe\_native.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe
    copying src\markupsafe\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe
    running egg_info
    writing src\MarkupSafe.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\MarkupSafe.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\MarkupSafe.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'src\MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying src\markupsafe\_speedups.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\markupsafe
    running build_ext
    building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
    error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rohit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7tccrr01\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rohit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7tccrr01\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q_wdekk3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, PyCharm uses pip to manage project packages. To manage Python packages for the project interpreter, select the Project Interpreter page in the project **Settings/Preferences** or select **Interpreter Settings** in the Python Interpreter widget.

Select *File* -> *Settings* -> *Project:* project_name -> *Project Interpreter*. Click the **+** button which is marked by the mouse cursor in the screenshot to install Python packages in the selected project.

[image: project Settings]

Search for Flask. Select it and click the *Install Package* button in the lower left corner of the Available Packages window to install it. PyCharm will automatically choose the package version for you or you can check the checkbox to the left of *Specify version* and select the package version from the *Specify version* dropdown menu.

[image: install Flask]

Whenever you [install a Python package](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) specifically for a project, PyCharm adds the packages that were installed to the project's venv directory where PyCharm will find them automatically.

PyCharm does not automatically find your globally installed Python packages unless the project has been configured to find them. To do this select the *Inherit global-site packages* option when you create a new project.

Select *File* -> *New Project* to create a new project. Click the triangle marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot to show the new project's options.

[image]

Then check the *Inherit global-site packages* checkbox and click the  <kbd>Create</kbd>  button in the lower right corner of the Create Project window.

[image]