# pip install error - ModuleNotFoundError when package already installed (Requirement already satisfied)

Tags: python, import, beautifulsoup, module

I'm trying to get started with BeautifulSoup but I'm having trouble installing and importing bs4. I type pip install beautifulsoup4 into the command prompt, and receive these two messages:

Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\jzhen\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (4.8.2)

Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in c:\users\jzhen\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (1.9.5)

However, when I run a program with just the single line

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I get the error

```
File "c:/Users/jzhen/OneDrive/Desktop/PriceUpdate.py", line 1, in <module>
 import bs4ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple Python versions installed in your system maybe `import bs4` returned an `No module named 'bs4'` error because you haven't installed beautifulsoup4 for the currently running Python interpreter. If you use `python3 -m pip install` instead of `pip install` then you know pip will be using and installing for your default Python 3.x interpreter.

```
python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

If  the currently running Python interpreter is Python 2.x the alternative to the above command is:

```
python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

If the Python program is running in an IDE, then maybe your project is not configured to find Python packages that were installed globally by pip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422188

Comment: I tried running python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4 then running my program but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Are you running the program inside an IDE or from the command line? If it's an IDE then maybe your project is not configured to find the packages that were installed globally by pip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422188

Answer (score 0):

One solution, without virtual `environment`: I have 2 versions, i.e. `python3.6` and `python3.7`

To fix these difficulties I also met with this kind of "`site-package`" , and because I have no "`sudo`" right on my windows 7 PC , this works for me : two installation "`declaratives`" as followed:

```
C:/Applications/Python/Python36/Scripts/pip3.6.exe install bs4  
C:/Applications/Python/Python36/Scripts/pip3.6.exe install beautifulsoup4
 
C:/Applications/Python/Python37/Scripts/pip3.7.exe install bs4  
C:/Applications/Python/Python37/Scripts/pip3.7.exe install beautifulsoup4
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you working on any virtual environment? If yes then install bs4 separately in that environment using terminal. If you are using virtual environment then possibly its is not using global packages available so you'll have to install in activated virtual environment.